# Racket code to find missing ranges

Tags: lisp, racket

I'm doing some toy problems [in a variety of languages](https://github.com/togakangaroo/daily-programmer/tree/master/missing-ranges#more-idomatic-racket) and wanted to do the following in Racket Lisp.

---

Given a sorted integer array `nums`, where the range of elements are in the inclusive range `[lower, upper]`, return its missing ranges.

```
0, 1, 3, 50, 75
```

Lower: `0`

Upper: `99`

Expected Output:

```
["2", "4->49", "51->74", "76->99"]
```

---

As you can see on the linked page I had to take two whacks at it but eventually came up with the following. How does it look? Is it idiomatic? Could I have done certain things far better?

```
(define (missing-ranges nums lower upper)
  (in-generator
   (define (yield-missing-range current num)
     (yield (if (eq? num (add1 current))
                (~a current)
                (~a current "->" (sub1 num)))))
   (let recur ([remaining-nums nums]
               [current lower])
     (match remaining-nums
       [(cons num rest-nums) (if (< current num)
                                 (begin
                                   (yield-missing-range current num)
                                   (recur rest-nums num))
                                 (recur rest-nums (add1 current)))]
       ['() (cond [(<= current upper)
                   (yield-missing-range current (add1 upper))])]))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems to me quite complex, with iterations, recursions, and the use of `match`.

Here is an alternative version with a simple linear recursion, where the result is given with lists and not with strings.

```
(define (missing-ranges nums lower upper)
  (cond ((> lower upper) '())
        ((null? nums) (list (list lower upper)))
        ((= lower (car nums)) (missing-ranges (cdr nums) (+ lower 1) upper))
        ((= (car nums) (+ 1 lower)) (cons (list lower) (missing-ranges nums (+ lower 1) upper)))
        (else (cons (list lower (- (car nums) 1)) (missing-ranges (cdr nums) (+ (car nums) 1) upper)))))

(missing-ranges '(0 1 3 50 75) 0 99)
'((2) (4 49) (51 74) (76 99))

(missing-ranges '(8) 0 99)
'((0 7) (9 99))

(missing-ranges '() 0 99)
'((0 99))

(missing-ranges '(3 9 88 99) 0 99)
'((0 2) (4 8) (10 87) (89 98))

(missing-ranges '(0 99) 0 99)
'((1 98))

(missing-ranges '(1 2 3) 1 3)
'()
```

Comment: Yeah, the string thing was an original requirement (though I control the requirements). I suppose taking those output lists and stringifying could just be a separate step. I also wanted to use generators specifically, though I think that should still be possible with your version